# Card game, off color write-in responses.

Tags: identify-this-game

Ran into this game at a brewery out of state. Can't find it in stores, and internet searches have turned up nothing.

It involves a player drawing a card, and the respondents writing an off-color or silly answer on sheets of paper (that come with the game).

The player then chooses funniest/most creative amongst the responses.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I submit [Balderdash](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/163/balderdash) as a possibility. Since the OP doesn't mention what is *on* the card the player draws, it's hard to say what the game might be. Also Balderdash players aren't directed specifically to be off color, but who *isnt*?

Answer (score 0):

While it uses dry-erase cards rather than plain paper, this sounds just like [Say Anything](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/33604/say-anything), although the aim is usually to write the answer which the question-asker will agree with the most (and there's a side-game of everyone "betting" on which of the given answers will be picked)

Answer (score 0):

Could also be [Wise and Otherwise](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2652/wise-and-otherwise).  Normally, the players agree on which is best or what they think is the most authentic, but we've played it where the reader decides as well.

Answer (score 0):

This could be [The Game of Things](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/26845/english-edition).  I know it comes with papers to write responses on.  One player draws a card and everyone writes a response.  Once all the responses are in the player who read the card reads the responses and tries to guess who wrote what, and scores points for guessing people correctly.